# How can I fix "no module named cv2"?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, dlib

Yesterday it seems like my OpenCV is working fine, but today when I reinstall and hit repair the python that I was using. I can't access import cv2 anymore. I tried to reinstall python and reinstall OpenCV but it's not working too. How can I fix this? When I import cv2 at cmd it seems to be working [(cmd screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDmsY.jpg) but  when I used python at the visual studio 2019 it says "no module named cv2" [visual studio screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxtXF.jpg). How can I fix this? Please help.

Comment: did you pip install opencv?

Comment: Run the following to see if `cv2` is available to your environment.
`pip list | grep -i cv2`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 2 enter the following:

```
pip show opencv-python
```

If you're using Python 3 enter the following:

```
pip3 show opencv-python
```

Can you see information about opencv-python package? (name, version, summary..etc)

1. If yes then ensure Python is added to PATH and you're running the Python version where the opencv package is installed.
2. If no then you didn't install opencv-python.

If you're using Python 2 enter the following:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

If you're using Python 3 enter the following:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Comment: You should give the name attribute for pip show.  `pip3 show opencv-python`